# Lightroom Classic CC unable to access photos on an OSX FUSE-mounted Veracrypt volume

Tags: macos, fuse, veracrypt, adobe-lightroom, macfuse

For privacy, especially while travelling, I maintain my photo library in this arrangement:

- Lightroom catalogue file inside a Veracrypt volume on an external SSD
- Original photos inside a Veracrypt volume on a separate, larger, external HDD
- Both Veracrypt volumes are formatted Mac OS Extended and mounted exclusively on macOS

This was working fine (speed-wise as well), until I updated from Lightroom CC to the new Lightroom Classic CC.

There's no problem opening the catalogue file, but when I attempt to import new photos from the other Veracrypt volume, the list of sources in Lightroom Classic CC's 'Import' window now shows `OSXFUSE Volume 1 (Veracrypt)` and `OSXFUSE Volume 2 (Veracrypt)`, which appear empty; whereas Lightroom CC showed their proper names and was able to navigate the folders inside.

Both macOS and FUSE are up to date.

How can I fix this? Alternatively, I'm open to other arrangements for keeping my Lightroom catalogue and photos local and encrypted.

Comment: After waiting a while, I cross-posted this question to the [Adobe forum](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9924821), where it has received a reply but remains unresolved.

Comment: For anyone else with this issue: the best alternative seems to be to use OSX's native encryption, by formatting a drive/partition as "Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)". This doesn't offer two factor authentication using a keyfile(s), as Veracrypt does.